# How does one set keyword "block" in plt.show() equal to True by default?

Tags: matplotlib

For some reason, I need to set the keyword "block" equal to True explicitly, so that plots are shown when I run a script from the bash shell. (I don't need that when I run it from the ipython shell). How can I set that argument to True by default as nearly everyone seems to have it?

Sample:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])

plt.show(block=True)
```

I would like plots to show up even if that argument isn't set to True explicitly, that is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])

plt.show()
```

My matplotlibrc contains:

backend      : MacOSX

interactive  : True

toolbar      : toolbar2
timezone     : UTC

Comment: The default blocking behavior is set by if `plt.ion()` has been called or not.

Comment: Also, did you change the `interactive` key in you rcparams file?

Comment: Thanks, @tcaswell Can you elaborate that? I haven't called plt.ion(). You have my full code within my question. I think I downloaded a rcparams file I found somewhere. I'll try to find that file and let you know.

Comment: @tcaswell I have edited my answer with some information contained in my matplotlibrc file. Interactive is set to True. What does this mean?

Comment: Remove the interactive entry (or set it to false) and it will work as expected

Comment: @tcaswell What does that mean? Is there any other implication if I set it to False?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'interactive' mode of mpl determines the behavior of `plt.show`. If in 'interactive' mode, it assumes that there is something else managing the GUI event loop.  When running a script with

```
python -i script.py
```

will drop you into an interactive shell.  When siting in the REPL, there is integration between the python REPL loop and the GUI event loop which allows the GUI loop to run in the background, which makes the figure 'interactive'.  If 'interactive' mode was *not* on in this case, you would not get the prompt until you have closed the figure.

'interactive' mode can be enabled either by calling `plt.ion()` or by setting the `'interactive'` key in `matplotlibrc`.

I strongly suggest that you leave the rcparam value to be `False`.

Comment: This has annoyed me forever, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
kwargs = dict(type='candle',mav=(10),volume=True,figratio=(11,8),figscale=0.85, block=True)

mpf.plot(dfless, **kwargs, style='classic')
```

putting it inside the kwargs  worked well for me